# Importing external JavaScript file in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using the Vue CLI and I want to import a JavaScript file that is hosted on another server. With everything I tried I get the same error as shown below.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? How can I import an external JS file?

My Vue file is shown below.

```
<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <template lang="pug"> -->
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>Test</p>

    <button @click="doSomething">Say hello.</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestFile from "https://.../src/TestFile.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: "<h1>anything</h1>"
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await TestFile.build();
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      alert(message);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <style lang="scss"> -->
<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `import` to `fetch the modules from the URL`, but there is a trick that you can do to use the `scripts from the URL`.

It's similar to attaching CDNJS's script. The solution is that you need to create the element and then append that element in the document's script.

The best solution would be, use a mounted lifecycle and then create and append it.

**Example Importing FontAwesome CDN Script:**

```
mounted() {
      let fontAwesome = document.createElement('script')
      fontAwesome.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js')
      document.head.appendChild(fontAwesome)
    },
```

In this way registering script will give you your functions access in global object `window`.

For example, now I can access some of the cool properties of FontAwesome like this:

```
window.FontAwesome.config
```

Comment: Thanks! Importing like this doesn't give me any errors. But how can I call a function from this JS file in my Vue component?

Comment: @inbarazulay you can call from window global object.

Comment: @InbarAzulay, I updated the answer; I hope this will help you.